# Prove that$\>$for $x\neq1$ and k ${\in}\> \textbf{Z}_{\geq0}$,$\>\sum_{j=0}^{k}x^{j}=\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, geometric-series

My response was as follows:

We may test our base case, that is when $k=0$. This computes to $x^{0}=\frac{1-x^{1}}{1-x}$ which equates to $1=1$. Whence $k=0$ holds. Therefore, such a statement $P_{k} :=x\neq1$ and k ${\in}\> \textbf{Z}_{\geq0}$,$\>\sum_{j=0}^{k}x^{j}=\frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}$ is assumed to be true.

Subsequently, our inductive hypothesis is formulated in evaluating the statement $P_{k+1}$. When prompted with such a dilemma, what may be useful is to write out the individual elements of the sequence to be added on our left hand side. For example, $$\>\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}x^{j}=\frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x}$$ may be written as $$x^{1}+x^{2}+x^{3}+\dots+x^{k-1}+x^{k}+x^{k+1}=\frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x}$$ This may be further made intuitive when we evaluate both sides as such and multiply $(1-x)$ by our left hand side expression. $$(x^{0}+x^{1}+x^{2}+\dots+x^{k-1}+x^{k}+x^{k+1})\cdot(1-x)=1-(x\cdot x \cdot x \cdot x^{k-1})$$
 Then $$(x^{0}+x^{1}+x^{2}...+x^{k-1}+x^{k}+x^{k+1})-(x^{1}+x^{2}+x^{3}+\dots+x^{k}+x^{k+1}+x^{k+2})=1-(x\cdot x \cdot x \cdot x^{k-1})$$ Finally this rationalizes to $x^{0}-x^{k+2}=1-x^{k+2}$ which completes are induction step.

The statement $P_{k+1}$ holds as   $1-x^{k+2}=1-x^{k+2}$ is true. By the principle of mathematical induction our original equality remains.  ////

Is my solution adequate? Would further proof be needed to show that this holds for $x 
\neq 1$?

Comment: You don't really need induction here. Your idea of proof is correct but you can remove the base case and inductive assumption. You can just prove it for a general $k$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof by induction is correct. However, it is a little convoluted, in my opinion. Here is how I would do it by induction.

The verification of the base case $k = 0$ is fine as it stands.

The induction hypothesis is formulated as follows: if $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{> 0}$ and $x \neq 1$, then $$\sum_{j=0}^k x^j = \frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}.$$

Now, we want to check that for $x\neq 1$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$, we have $$\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} x^j = \frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x}.$$
Working with the left hand side, we get
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=0}^{k+1} x^j &= \left( \sum_{j=0}^k x^j \right) + x^{k+1}\\
&= \frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x} + x^{k+1}\\
&= \frac{1-x^{k+1} + x^{k+1} - x^{k+2}}{1-x}\\
&= \frac{1-x^{k+2}}{1-x}.
\end{align}
Hence, by the principle of mathematical induction, we have proved our claim.

---

You can also prove the claim directly, without using induction. Let
$$S = \sum_{j=0}^k x^j.$$ Then, $$xS = \sum_{j=1}^{k+1} x^j.$$
Hence, $$S - xS = x^0 - x^{k+1} \implies S = \frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}.$$

Comment: I agree that this is a cleaner proof. However, would we need to verify that our equality isn't equal when x=1 in order to validate the original claim?

Comment: @sardinsky not really. As I understand it, the statement given is "If $x \neq 1$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, then *<something happens>*". So we have verified that when the hypotheses hold, the conclusion is also true. There is no need to say anything about the case when the hypotheses do not hold, unless explicitly asked.

Comment: @sardinsky however, should one be curious as to what happens when we plug in $x = 1$ on both sides, then that is a valid check to perform for one's satisfaction. And yes, in this case it is true that the formula does not hold when $x = 1$.

Comment: Absolutely satisfying to check the result when x=1. Thanks for your speedy response.

Comment: @sardinsky glad to be of help :)